# Como reduzir a largura do campo usando css?

Tags: css

Recebi um código para incorporar no site, mas não estou conseguindo reduzir a largura no campo pra preencher e-mail. Abaixo segue o código. Desde já agradeço.

Código para colocar no head:

```
<script src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/widgets.superlogica.net/embed.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*{literal}<![CDATA[*/
superlogica.require("condominios");
superlogica.condominios("areadocondomino","areaCondominio","vgm","1");
/*]]>{/literal}*/
</script>
<div id="areaCondominio"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O script gera um `iframe` e você não pode alterar o visual dentro de um `iframe` a não ser que você tenha acesso ao css do documento HTML exibido, neste caso não é possível. 
[Saiba mais sobre iframe aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)